# combination sum of array - dynamic programming - fix needed

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have implemented the code to output all the different unique possibilities of getting a target sum from the elements of input array. for example given the `arr -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10]` and target sum of 8, the output should be `[1, 2, 5], [1, 7], [2, 6], [3, 5]`. In my code below, I get an extra `[2, 3]` in the output. Also for the target of 33, with the same input list as above I get strange results I need some assistance here in fixing this code.

```
public class CombinationSum {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Set<Integer>> resultList = new ArrayList<Set<Integer>>();
        int[] arr={10,1,2,7,6,3,5};
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

        int target=8;
        sumCombinations(resultList, temp, target, arr, 0);
        System.out.printf("target is %s; resultList is %s%n",target,resultList);

        int target2=33;
        List<Integer> temp2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Set<Integer>> resultList2 = new ArrayList<Set<Integer>>();
        sumCombinations(resultList2, temp2, target2, arr, 0);
        System.out.printf("target is %s; resultList is %s%n",target2,resultList2);          
    }

    public static void sumCombinations(List<Set<Integer>> resultList, List<Integer> temp, int target, int[] arr,
            int start){

       for (int i=start;i<arr.length;i++){
           if (arr[i]==target){
               temp.add(arr[i]);
               Set<Integer> scratch = new HashSet<Integer>(temp);
               if (!resultList.contains(scratch))
                   resultList.add(scratch);
           }
           else if (target>arr[i]){
               temp.add(arr[i]);
               sumCombinations(resultList, temp, target-arr[i], arr, start+1);
           }
           else  return; 
               if (temp.size()>0)
              temp.remove(temp.size()-1);
           }
       }
    }
```

Output:

```
target is 8; resultList is [[1, 2, 5], [1, 7], [2, 3], [2, 6], [3, 5]]`

target is 33; resultList is [[1, 2, 3, 7, 10], [1, 2, 5, 10], [1, 2, 6, 7, 10], 
[1, 2, 10], [1, 3, 6, 10], [1, 3, 5, 7, 10], [1, 3, 6, 7, 10], [1, 5, 7, 10], 
[1, 5, 6, 10], [1, 5, 6, 7], [1, 6, 7], [1, 6, 10], [2, 3, 6, 10], [2, 5, 7, 10],
[2, 6, 7, 10], [2, 3, 5, 10], [2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10], [2, 3, 7], [2, 5, 6, 10], 
[2, 5, 7], [2, 5, 6, 7], [2, 6, 7], [2, 7, 10], [3, 7, 10], [3, 5, 7, 10], 
[3, 5, 6, 10], [3, 6, 7], [3, 5, 6, 7], [3, 5, 10], [3, 6, 7, 10], [3, 10], 
[5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7, 10], [5, 6, 10], [5, 7], [6, 7], [6, 7, 10]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive call

```
sumCombinations(resultList, temp, target - arr[i], arr, start + 1);
```

should be like this:

```
sumCombinations(resultList, temp, target - arr[i], arr, i + 1);
```

Because the way this recursion is done once you are adding the number i to `temp` all the combinations of picking the previous `0..i-1` numbers will already be considered, you only have to call `sumCombinations` to test combinations after the last addition.

This caused some numbers to be reconsidered and added multiple times, for example the wrong solution [2, 3] for 8 was actually [2, 3 ,3] that when converted to a Set deleted the repeated 3.

Comment: Thanks, thats an important observation. one thing though, to make this work without intial sorting; should I replace `else return;` for a recursive call of `sumCombinations(resultList, temp, target + temp.remove(temp.size()-1), arr, i + 1);`

Comment: It's not exactly about that `else return;` if it's not sorted the previous `else if (target > arr[i])` makes no sense. So if you want to rework that you have to change both parts accordingly. But sorting is fine, it's very fast compared to the rest of the algorithm, and allows you to cut some recursion branches very easily.